# How to deploy multiple .net core projects in a single elastic beanstalk server?

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a single solution with 2 projects - https://github.com/vickyrathee/dotnet-test-app

1. My Website: **dotnet-test-website** (domain.com)
2. My API: **dotnet-test-api** (api.domain.com)

How can I configure my projects to be deployed on single Ubuntu/Amazon linux server?

I already tried using the `Urls` option on `appsettings.json` to set port `5001` for API project and `5002` for website project as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365277/how-to-specify-the-port-an-asp-net-core-application-is-hosted-on/55276201)

https://github.com/vickyrathee/dotnet-test-app/blob/master/dotnet-test-app/appsettings.json

```
{
  "Urls" :  "http://localhost:5001"
}
```

But as per the EB logs, it seems to trying port `5000` instead what I defined in `appsettings.json`

```
----------------------------------------
/var/log/nginx/error.log
----------------------------------------
2021/02/14 09:11:24 [error] 3583#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.10.146, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "172.31.26.188"
2021/02/14 09:11:39 [error] 3583#0: *3 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.10.146, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "172.31.26.188"
2021/02/14 09:11:54 [error] 3583#0: *5 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.10.146, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "172.31.26.188"
```

Additionally, how to publish it correctly in separate folders, So that there are no conflict between them. EB allow single `zip` file upload with `appsettings.json` on root, while I have two with some other files as well in common and can't just put them on single directory to zip. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Nginx on EB uses port 5000 by [defaut](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/dotnet-linux-platform-nginx.html). You can use ` PORT` env variable to change that.

Comment: @Marcin I can't use PORT env variable because I want to deploy multiple projects on same server....so setting env variable will just map to one.